# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c, ms-access

I have a problem when i m connection with access database then i m getting a error Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. and my code is :

```
 string str = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Geeta/Desktop/Database2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(str);
        conn.Open();
        string query = "insert into data (FirstName,Email,Password,Address) values ('" + 
            txt_fstname.Text + "','" + txt_email.Text + "', '" + 
            txt_pass.Text + "', '" + txt_add.Text + "')";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query,conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

plz suggest me.

"Thanks"

Comment: Could you add the error message? and the query string that is generated at runtime. Perhaps there are some special characters in the textboxes.

Comment: Please, don't create query manually appending strings, integers, dates into command: use `Parameters` and your life will be easier !!!

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327) anybody?

Comment: First step in debugging is to print (or log) the string `query`; what does it contain when you get the error?

Comment: Creating query in that way if user uses a `'` in password your query fails and the same for all other fields!! Do you check user input before passing it in the query? Do you sanitize it?

Answer (score 3):

Password is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in Jet/ACE SQL so you must enclose it in square brackets:

```
string query = "insert into data (FirstName,Email,[Password],Address) values ('" +
```