# No value given for one or more required parameters.()

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a problem, when i m login the error is occured that No value given for one or more required parameters.

```
protected void imgbtn_login_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int UserId = 0;
    string str = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=pathto.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(str);
    conn.Open();
    string query = "select * from Users where LoginName='" + txt_logname.Text + "' and Password='" + txt_pass.Text + "';";
    OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter(query,conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    try
    {
        UserId = Int32.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString());

        //btn_LogIn.Text = "Login Succeded";
        Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    txt_logname.Text = " ";
    txt_pass.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Empty catch blocks are evil. Avoid them.

Comment: Concatenating SQL in the manner you are doing is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - avoid this and use parameterized queries.

Comment: Please indicate where in your code the error is occurring. I don't think the code you posted has anything to do with it.

Comment: You're doing same mistakes even if we tried to advise you in your previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137279/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement

Answer (score 3):

Password is a reserved word. Put it in square brackets [Password]

See [Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137279/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement/10137621#10137621)

Comment: @Marco Should I have use caps? :D