# Syntax error in insert into statement - what's the error?

Tags: ms-access

this is the full code here for a button to add data to 2 different tables the weird thing is that i have another form wih a button wih similar function and it works fine wih the same statment
               Option Compare Database

```
     Private Sub addbutton_Click()

     CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Clients(F_Name,L_Name,Phone_Number,E-mail,Gender,Date_of_Birth) " & "VALUES(" & Me.textfname & ",'" & Me.textlname & "','" & Me.textpnumber & "','" & Me.textemail & "','" & Me.textgender & "','-" & Me.textdob & "')"
     CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Accounts(F_Name,L_Name,Username,Password,accounttype) " & "VALUES(" & Me.textfname & ",'" & Me.textlname & "','" & Me.textusername & "','" & Me.textpassword & "','" & Me.textaccountype & "')"

clientssubform.Form.Requery


     End Sub
```

Comment: After all this SQL-injectable text concatenation, what's the actual SQL query being executed?

Comment: am still new to access how do i get that for u

Comment: Put the SQL statement into a string variable, inspect in debug?

Comment: this is the full code am using sorry if i don understand how to get you the SQL query and i appreciate the help

Comment: Use `Debug.Print`: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137279/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Password is a reserved word, so use `[Password]`.

Second, a date expression must be wrapped in octothorpes: `#2017/04/24#`

Also, if you won't use parameters, even though recommended, use a function like this to concatenate your values:

```
' Converts a value of any type to its string representation.
' The function can be concatenated into an SQL expression as is
' without any delimiters or leading/trailing white-space.
'
' Examples:
'   SQL = "Select * From TableTest Where [Amount]>" & CSql(12.5) & "And [DueDate]<" & CSql(Date) & ""
'   SQL -> Select * From TableTest Where [Amount]> 12.5 And [DueDate]< #2016/01/30 00:00:00#
'
'   SQL = "Insert Into TableTest ( [Street] ) Values (" & CSql(" ") & ")"
'   SQL -> Insert Into TableTest ( [Street] ) Values ( Null )
'
' Trims text variables for leading/trailing Space and secures single quotes.
' Replaces zero length strings with Null.
' Formats date/time variables as safe string expressions.
' Uses Str to format decimal values to string expressions.
' Returns Null for values that cannot be expressed with a string expression.
'
' 2016-01-30. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CSql( _
    ByVal Value As Variant) _
    As String

    Const vbLongLong    As Integer = 20
    Const SqlNull       As String = " Null"

    Dim Sql             As String
    Dim LongLong        As Integer

    #If Win32 Then
        LongLong = vbLongLong
    #End If
    #If Win64 Then
        LongLong = VBA.vbLongLong
    #End If

    Select Case VarType(Value)
        Case vbEmpty            '    0  Empty (uninitialized).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbNull             '    1  Null (no valid data).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbInteger          '    2  Integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbLong             '    3  Long integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbSingle           '    4  Single-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDouble           '    5  Double-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbCurrency         '    6  Currency.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDate             '    7  Date.
            Sql = Format(Value, " \#yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss\#")
        Case vbString           '    8  String.
            Sql = Replace(Trim(Value), "'", "''")
            If Sql = "" Then
                Sql = SqlNull
            Else
                Sql = " '" & Sql & "'"
            End If
        Case vbObject           '    9  Object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbError            '   10  Error.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbBoolean          '   11  Boolean.
            Sql = Str(Abs(Value))
        Case vbVariant          '   12  Variant (used only with arrays of variants).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDataObject       '   13  A data access object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDecimal          '   14  Decimal.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbByte             '   17  Byte.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case LongLong           '   20  LongLong integer (Valid on 64-bit platforms only).
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbUserDefinedType  '   36  Variants that contain user-defined types.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbArray            ' 8192  Array.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case Else               '       Should not happen.
            Sql = SqlNull
    End Select

    CSql = Sql & " "

End Function
```

Study the in-line comments for usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this part of code

```
"VALUES(" & Me.textfname & ",'" &
```

to this

```
"VALUES('" & Me.textfname & "','" &
```

in both lines