# Avoid Invalid use of Null error when the field is empty

Tags: ms-access, vba

I created a form in Access 2010 and I fill in the form based on text boxes (B and C) and selection form a combobox (A). The problem is if any of the text box left empty I get “Invalid use of Null” error. I noticed I can avoid this error if I Dim the text boxes as Variant instead of Integer. I am not sure if this is the right solution. Can I change the following script to avoid this error?

```
Private Sub ABCBoxEnter_Click()
Dim A As String
Dim B As Integer
Dim C As Integer
If Not IsNull(Me!ComboBox.Value) Then
    A = Me!ComboBox.Value
    B = Afield
    C = Bfield
    values = "VALUES ("
    values = values & "'" & ID & "','" & A & "','" & B & "','" & C & "')"
    SQL = "INSERT  INTO ContactTable (ID, A, B, C)"
    SQL = SQL & values
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
    Me.B.Value = ""
    Me.C.Value = ""
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Nz*:

```
values = values & "'" & Nz(ID) & "','" & Nz(A) & "','" & Nz(B) & "','" & Nz(C) & "')"
```

Or, better, implement my function [CSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589800/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-whats-the-error/43591778#43591778)

Comment: That will throw an invalid use of null on `A = Me!ComboBox.Value` if `Me!ComboBox.Value` is `Null`, except when `A` is specified as a `Variant`. `A = CSql(Me!ComboBox.Value)` and the same for `B` and `C` would be a more valid approach when going for `CSql`. Then `B` and `C` should be a string.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: No, that is ruled out by the _If_ just before (the line above). But see my added link to _CSql_.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I used the Nz function as follows: '" & Nz(B, “N/A”) & "','" & Nz(C, “N/A”) & "' and it is working fine with the first  data entry and I can see N/A where there is no entry but for the following entries I just received blank cells where no entries!! Any idea why this is happing and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I have past the bit I am interested in. The full command is: values = values & "'" & Nz(ID) & "','" & Nz(A) & "','" & Nz(B, “N/A”) & "','" & Nz(C,“N/A”) & "')". I did not use Nz with ID or A. Even when I used with ID and A, it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Still, if ID is a key, and with that name it should be, it must be assigned a value.

Comment: The ID in this table - which is not a primary key - is populated via a relationship from another table - which is the main table with ID as a primary key.

Comment: Then it is supposed to have a value. If not, as you have seen, the insert will fail.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, the problem was in Me.B.Value = ""
    Me.C.Value = "". I changed "" to Null and I can get N/A in any empty entry :)

Answer (score 1):

The big question is: what do you want to happen when a value is `Null`.

As you noticed, integers and strings can't contain `Null`, while a `Variant` can. Dimming your intermediary variables as `Variant` is an approach that's okay in your code. You can also use the `Nz` function to replace `Null` with an empty string if referred to as a string, or 0 if referred to as an integer.

Note that if you were to remove the `'` apostrophes from your SQL statement, you would run into an error, and you would have to use `Iif(IsNull(B), "Null", B)` where you just have `B` in the SQL statement.