# MS Access VBA Update Field with Null or Empty String

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to update a MS Access table via VBA from a DAO Recordset.  The problem is that if one of the field values is null.  The code errors out.  Is there something like `IsNull(rst.Fields("FirstName").value,"")` that I can use?  I tried using this but it throws the error "Invalid Use of Null".  Please help.

```
strSQL = Update myTable SET myField ='" & rs.Fields("recField").Value & "' where id = 25
db.Execute strSQL
```

in this instance, `rs.Fields("recField").Value` is Null

Comment: Please edit to include the entire method so we can see what your code is trying to achieve

Comment: Provide code. Are you setting VBA string variables? Only variant type variable can hold Null. I don't allow empty strings in tables but if you want: `Nz(rst!FirstName, "")`.

Answer (score 0):

`NZ` is MS Access's Built-In function to handle nulls

> Nz ( variant, [ value_if_null ] )

- - `Nz (rst.Fields("FirstName").Value, 0)`

Alternatively you could use the VBA `IIF` statement.

> IIf( Expression, TruePart, FalsePart )

To return an Empty string use:

`Nz (rst.Fields("FirstName").Value, "")` or `IIf(rst.Fields("FirstName").Value, "", rst.Fields("FirstName").Value)`

If the field that you are updating is numeric then you'll need to return a Zero value if null:

`Nz (rst.Fields("FirstName").Value, 0)` or `IIf(rst.Fields("FirstName").Value, 0, rst.Fields("FirstName").Value)`

Comment: Don't know enough Access-VBA, but (a) wouldn't NULL evaluate to `False` in an `If`/`IIf` (because it isn't equal to `True`)? (b) would the OP be able to use `...SET myField =" & IIf(IsNull(rst.Fields("recField").Value), "NULL", "'" & rst.Fields("FirstName").Value) & "'") & " where ...` if they actually wanted to set the `myField` field to a NULL if the `recField` field was NULL?  (just in case they want to promulgate the NULLs rather than changing it to an empty string or a zero)

Comment: [Application.Nz Method (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-nz-method-access) uses `IIf(IsNull(varFreight), 0, varFreight) ` as it's example but you are correct that Null will evaluate as false.   So I guess the `IsNull()` function isn't needed.

Comment: Don't you mean the `IsNull()` function **is** needed?  `IIf(varFreight, 0, varFreight)` would return `0` if `varFreight` evaluated to `True` and would return `varFreight` if `varFreight` evaluated to `False` (which it will do if it is `Null`).  Argh - too early in the morning to be thinking of logical variables!

Comment: You would use `Null` without the  quotation marks (e.g. `UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.T1 = Null;`)

Comment: I think that is what my suggestion in (b) creates as the SQL, so I guess I got that bit right :) :)

Comment: `IIf(varFreight, varFreight, 0)` would be comparable to  `IIf(IsNull(varFreight), 0, varFreight)`.  I would still use the `IsNull` to clarify the statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152100/discussion-between-yowe3k-and-thomas-inzina).

Answer (score 0):

You can use my *CSql* function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589800/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-whats-the-error/43591778#43591778) like:

```
strSQL = "Update myTable Set myField = " & CSql(rs.Fields("recField").Value) & " Where id = 25"
```

That will for a value return:

```
"Update myTable Set myField = 'ValueOfField' Where id = 25"
```

and for a value of Null:

```
"Update myTable Set myField = Null Where id = 25"
```