# Access VBA DLookup Multiple Critiera based on Variables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've been poking around with the below code and cannot get it to work.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim RecRLs As Recordset
Dim sTripCode, sVanNum As Integer
Dim sDepDate, sArrivalDate As Date
Dim sRoomRate As Currency
Set RecRLs = db.OpenRecordset("qryRLRoomListRates", dbOpenSnapshot)

sTripCode = DLookup("[TourCodeID]", "tblTripCodes", "[TourCode]=[Forms]![frmRMSBuildRLs]![tboxTourCode]")
sDepDate = [Forms]![frmRMSBuildRLs]![tboxDepartureDate]
sVanNum = [Forms]![frmRMSBuildRLs]![tboxVanNumber]
sArrivalDate = RecRLs!ArrivalDate


sRoomRate = DLookup("[RateTwinHosCab]", "tblRLRatesByTrip", "[TourCode] = " 
& sTripCode & " AND [DepartureDate] = " & sDepDate & " AND [VanNumber] = " & 
sVanNum & " AND [ArrivalDate] = " & sArrivalDate)
```

The issue is that sRoomRate returns null.
I've MsgBox'd each of the variables: sTripCode, sDepDate, sVanNum, and sArrivalDate. They each return the correct result.

Any ideas why sRoomRate would return null? Thank you so much!

Comment: Does `sDepDate` contain a string such as `"#10/24/2017#"` or does it just contain a string such as `"10/24/2017"` or does it contain a date such as `10/24/2017`?

Comment: sDepDate contains the format: 10/24/2017 . no quotes or hashtags. thank you!

Comment: I should add all of the variables match. I.E. [TourCode] is a number field and sTripCode returns a number, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah you led me down the right path. Solution posted below.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to add the #s around the dates below:

```
sRoomRate = DLookup("[RateTwinHosCab]", "tblRLRatesByTrip", "[TourCode] = " & 
sTripCode & " AND [DepartureDate] = #" & sDepDate & "# AND [VanNumber] = " & 
sVanNum & " AND [ArrivalDate] = #" & sArrivalDate & "#")
```

Comment: You should probably explicitly format your dates using `= #" & Format(sDepDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# AND ...`.  Otherwise VBA will format them with whatever default date settings are in place, which might be a `"dd/mm/yyyy"` format for instance, and that could cause issues if anyone uses the code other than yourself.

Comment: That is only half of the solution.You miss the format as described by @YowE3K. Or use my `CSql` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589800/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-whats-the-error/43591778#43591778) for concatenating your values.