# VBA + SQL Server - Get Last ID Inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

Hope you can help - I'm having issues getting the last ID after INSERT.

So the environment - Access 2016, SQL Server and VBA

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
```

I have theses declared and then private sub.

```vb
Private Sub CreateOrderHeader()
Dim CustomerID As Integer
Dim OrderDate As String
Dim OrderStatus As String
Dim OrderValue As Double
Dim OrderNotes As String
Dim OrderPostageID As String
Dim OrderAddressID As String
Dim OrderBatchID As Integer
Dim OrderPayment As String
Dim OrderCourierID As String
Dim OrderAgentID As Integer
Dim OrderOutstanding As Double

CustomerID = tbxCusID
OrderDate = Format(Now)
OrderStatus = "InProcess"
OrderValue = txtTotal.value
OrderNotes = tbxNotes.value
OrderPostageID = txtPostage.Column(0)

If tbxCustomerAddress = tbxDeliveryAddress Then
    OrderAddressID = 3 'default customers address
Else
    'NEED TO GET CUSTOMER ADDRESS TO DO
End If
OrderBatchID = cmbBatch.Column(0)
OrderPayment = sPayMethod
OrderCourierID = cbxShipping.Column(0)
OrderAgentID = 0
OrderOutstanding = txtTotal.value

 Dim testvar As String

sql = "INSERT INTO dbo_OrderHeader " _
      & "(OrdCusID, OrdDate, OrdStatus, OrdValue, OrdNotes, OrdPostageID, OrdDelAddID,OrdBatchID,OrdPaymentMethod, OrdCourierID,ordAgentID, OrdOutstanding,OrdSource) " _
      & " VALUES ('" & CustomerID & "' ,'" & OrderDate & "', '" & OrderStatus & "', '" & OrderValue & "', '" & OrderNotes & "', '" & OrderPostageID & "','" & OrderAddressID & "','" & OrderBatchID & "','" & OrderPayment & "','" & OrderCourierID & "','" & OrderAgentID & "','" & OrderOutstanding & "', 1)"



DoCmd.RunSQL (sql)

sql = "SELECT @@IDENTITY As IDT"
RS.Open sql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
IDT = RS!IDT

MsgBox ("Succes - OrderHeader" & " '" & IDT & "'  ")
End Sub
```

I was expecting a result from this code:

```vb
sql = "SELECT @@IDENTITY As IDT"
RS.Open sql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
IDT = RS!IDT
```

But that gives me "0" as result.

Can you help please.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps relevant, see also the Access specific link embedded in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/186563/84206

Comment: I recommend a stored procedure, to prevent the possible problems I see with SQL injection.  The proc can do the insert and have an output parameter that gives you the ID.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to check - i'm not familiar with Store Procedures.

Comment: Consider also using [parameterization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47064696/1422451) with Access' `PARAMETERS` clause as some of those form values look to be open-ended for a clever user to inject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
Set db = CurrentDB
db.Execute(sql)

IDT = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)
Set db = Nothing
```

**NOTE**

Don't execute your insert query like `DoCmd.RunSQL (sql)` Instead follow the above approach.

Comment: Thanks - but this still returns 0.

Comment: It's great that your problem is sorted out. Don't forget to mark this answer as useful(upvote) :)

Comment: I would change @@IDENTITY to Scope_Identity() if possible. @@Identity is not limited to the scope of your transaction so it is possible to get an incorrect number returned.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse ... `Scope_Identity()` is [not supported in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186544/identity-after-insert-statement-always-returns-0/186565#comment11363929_186565). OP is running the Access engine to SQL Server linked table.