# Debugging Access VBA Currentdb.Execute

Tags: vba, ms-access, debugging

It says invalid insert statement when I run this code.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into invoices (Stateid, companyid, PaymentYear,InvoiceDate,Type,MethodofPayment,date,amount) " & _
"values('" & Me.StateID & "','cOOKIE','" & Me.PaymentYear & "', '" & Me.InvoiceDate & "'," _
& "'" & Me.Type & "','" & Me.MethodofPayment & "','" & Me.Date & "','" & Me.Amount & "');"
```

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, provide valid string expressions for the values - not everything is text - and respect reserved words:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into invoices (Stateid, companyid, PaymentYear, InvoiceDate, [Type], MethodofPayment, [date], amount) " & _
"Values('" & Me.StateID & "','cOOKIE'," & Me.PaymentYear & ", #" & Format(Me.InvoiceDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#, " & _
"'" & Me.Type & "','" & Me.MethodofPayment & "',#" & Format(Me.Date, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#," & Str(Me.Amount) & ");"
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized it later on.

Comment: Or use my _CSql_ function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589800/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-whats-the-error/43591778#43591778).