# What's wrong with this SQL code? (VBA MS Access)

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, ms-access

```
insertString = "INSERT INTO paymentRecord(paymentEventDate,paymentType,paymentRecordNotes,value,clientID,jobID) 
VALUES (recordDate,recordType,recordNotes,paymentValue,clientID,jobID);"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL insertString
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

This code returns a syntax error and I don't know why. All insert values and columns are correct.

The code is being used in a MS Access front-end with a MySQL database back-end.

Comment: Post the error please

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kiue0s

Comment: Don't paste pictures of error messages, put the actual error message into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must concatenate the values:

```
" .. VALUES (" & recordDate & "," & recordType & "," & recordNotes & "," & paymentValue & "," & clientID & "," & jobID)"
```

Also, the values must be formatted and delimited correctly, for example by using my function [CSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589800/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-whats-the-error/43591778#43591778).

Even better, use parameters.

Comment: Ok thankyou, I will try that. Though the confusing thing is that I have the same query working elsewhere in Access, but it's just inputting different values into a different table.

Comment: This hasn't worked. But as a general note. The correct concatenated code was `VALUES (" & recordDate & ",'" & recordType & "','" & recordNotes & "'," & paymentValue & "," & clientID & "," & jobID & ")"`  - Different delimiters for string variables and anything else (integer, date) Thanks anyway

Comment: OK, but the date must be formatted and delimited as well. See how in my link above.

Comment: Yeah. My code and your code are both same for parsing the date variable, I was saying that we'd need different formatting for sending string variables. With an apostrophe.