# Access VBA using SQL UPDATE

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using two Access databases (front end and back end).

My code for query work, but I get it to work with updating the database. What am I doing wrong?

I get a runtime error 3078 for the `DoCmd.RunSQL strSql` on line 25.

```vb
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & CurrentProject.Path & "\DB_Cryk.accdb"

cnn.Open strConnection

MemberID = txtMemberID.Value

strSql = "UPDATE Cryk " & _
"SET Membership = '" & txtMembership.Value & "', " & _
"    Memberstatus = '" & txtMemberstatus.Value & "', " & _
"    Membername = '" & txtMembername.Value & "', " & _
"    Memberaddress = '" & txtMemberaddress.Value & "', " & _
"    Memberzip = '" & txtMemberzip.Value & "', " & _
"    Membercity = '" & txtMembercity.Value & "', " & _
"    Memberphone = '" & txtMemberphone.Value & "', " & _
"    Membermail = '" & txtMembermail.Value & "', " & _
"    Memberyear = '" & txtMemberyear.Value & "', " & _
"    Dateofbirth = '" & txtDateofbirth.Value & "', " & _
"    Memberno = '" & txtMemberno.Value & "', " & _
"    Memberfee = '" & txtMemberfee.Value & "', " & _
"    Memberpayment = '" & txtMemberpayment.Value & "'" & _
"WHERE MemberID= '" & MemberID & "'"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSql

cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's wrong with this SQL code? (VBA MS Access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856631/whats-wrong-with-this-sql-code-vba-ms-access)

Comment: You assume that all fields are of data type Text, which they probably are not. Also, consider using _parameters_ to avoid the issue completely.

Comment: I would print out the resulting `strSql` string to see if it is valid SQL. I echo Gustav's sentiment, use parameters. String concatenation of SQL queries opens you up to SQL injection. Here's an example of using parameters in VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50102644/2675670

Comment: Thanks, I have very little experience with sql the last 15 years, so can you help with an example based on my code using parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Error 3078 indicates that the target table does not exist in your database.

Note that, although you open an ADO connection to the database `DB_Cryk.accdb`, you execute your SQL statement using the `DoCmd.RunSQL` method, which operates on the **current database**.

Instead, if you want the SQL to be executed in your `DB_Cryk.accdb` database, you should use the [`Execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/execute-method-ado-connection) method of the ADODB Connection object, e.g.:

```
cnn.Execute strsql
```

---

Where query parameterization is concerned, you may wish to refer to [this superb answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49509616/7531598), specifically, the 'Using ADO' section.

Comment: Thanks Lee :), now I just need to solve the datatypes issue

Comment: @KimK I have updated my answer to provide more information about using parameters with ADO.