# Any Function in Access VBA to work like if(me.Text01.value is null, 'null',me.Text01.value)

Tags: vba, ms-access, null, controls

I am writing the code below to insert control values into a table

```
currentdb.execute "insert into Table (AAA,AAB,AAC) values('"&me.Text1.value&"','"&me.text2.value&"','"&me.text3.value&")"
```

Sometimes one of these text boxes has no value. Is there a function I can use to write the statement in one sentence?

```
currentdb.execute "insert into Table (AAA,AAB,AAC) values('"&if(me.Text1.value is null,null,me.Text1.value)&"','"&if(me.text2.value is null, null,me.Text2.value)&"','"&if(me.text3.value is null, null,me.Texte.value)&")"
```

Because I dont want to construct many if else clause.

```
if isnull(me.Text1.value) then
...
else
...
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking for the [Nz Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c)

However, instead of writing the text box values into the `INSERT` statement text, you could execute a parameter query.  And that query statement text need not change based on whether or not any of the text boxes contain Null.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO YourTable (AAA, AAB, AAC) VALUES (p1, p2, p3);"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strInsert)
qdf.Parameters("p1").Value = Me.Text1.Value
qdf.Parameters("p2").Value = Me.Text2.Value
qdf.Parameters("p3").Value = Me.Text3.Value
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
Debug.Print "rows added: " & db.RecordsAffected
```

Answer (score 0):

Though parameters are neat, the direct answer to your question is my function [CSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589800/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-whats-the-error/43591778#43591778).

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it will insert empty string into table if TextBoxes have no value:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table (AAA,AAB,AAC) " & _
"VALUES ('" & Nz(Me.Text1.Value, '') & "','" & _
Nz(Me.Text2.Value, '') & " ','" & Nz(Me.Text3.Value, '') & ")"
```