# How can I fix my syntax error 3134 in this code?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

```vb
Private Sub Form_Close()

    Dim sSQL, stringSQL As String
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    sSQL = "SELECT BarCode, [Goods Name] FROM tblInventory WHERE BarCode='" & Me.ID & "'"
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
    If rst.EOF Then
        stringSQL = "INSERT INTO tblInventory(BarCode,[Goods Name],Unit,[Unit Price],[Initial Stock],[Current Stock],[Exit Item]) values('" & Me.ID & "','" & Me.GoodsName & "','" & Me.Unit & "'," & Replace(Format(Me.Price, "0.00"), ",", ".") & "," & Me.Amount & "," & Me.Amount & ",0)"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL [stringSQL]
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Else
        stringSQL = "UPDATE tblInventory SET [Current Stock]=[Current Stock]+" & Me.Amount & " WHERE BarCode='" & Me.ID & "'"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL (stringSQL)
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
    rst.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! WHen you post a wuestion that is just code, try to explain which one is your problem, where you got it... In fact, as it is just code, you can not apply code format and the readibility is really poor.

Comment: Don't not munge query strings with values.  Instead, learn to use parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note that this:

```vb
Dim sSQL, stringSQL As String
```

Results in `sSQL` being defined as a **Variant**, not a String; which, although will not cause your code to fail (since a Variant can hold data of any type), it will be memory inefficient.

Instead, you should use:

```vb
Dim sSQL As String, stringSQL As String
```

Or, perhaps more readable:

```vb
Dim sSQL As String
Dim stringSQL As String
```

---

Secondly, when invoking a function independently of any other expression, you should not surround the arguments with parentheses of any type.

In your code, on line **11** you have:

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL [stringSQL]
```

And on line **16** you have:

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL (stringSQL)
```

Both of these should be changed to:

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL stringSQL
```

Or, just supply the SQL string directly, e.g.:

```vb
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tblInventory SET [Current Stock]=[Current Stock]+" & Me.Amount & " WHERE BarCode='" & Me.ID & "'"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

---

Also, since you are only using the recordset to test whether a record exists, you could simplify this to a `DLookup` call, e.g.:

```vb
DLookup("BarCode","tblInventory","BarCode=Forms![YourForm]!ID")
```

And test whether or not this returns `Null` using `IsNull`:

```vb
If IsNull(DLookup("BarCode", "tblInventory", "BarCode=Forms![YourForm]!ID")) Then
    ...
Else
    ...
End If
```

---

Finally, it is much better practice to use a **parameterised query** in place of concatenating values within a SQL statement.

Using parameters offers two key advantages:

- Protects against SQL injection.
- Automatically handles SQL data types.

For example, consider the following code:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Close()
    If IsNull(DLookup("BarCode", "tblInventory", "BarCode=Forms![YourForm]!ID")) Then
        With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef _
            ( _
                "", _
                "insert into tblInventory(BarCode,[Goods Name],Unit,[Unit Price],[Initial Stock],[Current Stock],[Exit Item]) " & _
                "values(@id, @goodsname, @unit, @unitprice, @initstock, @stock, 0)" _
            )
            .Parameters(0) = Me.ID
            .Parameters(1) = Me.GoodsName
            .Parameters(2) = Me.Unit
            .Parameters(3) = Replace(Format(Me.Price, "0.00"), ",", ".")
            .Parameters(4) = Me.Amount
            .Parameters(5) = Me.Amount
            .Execute
        End With
    Else
        With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef _
            ( _
                "", _
                "update tblInventory set [Current Stock]=[Current Stock]+@amount where BarCode=@id" _
            )
            .Parameters(0) = Me.Amount
            .Parameters(1) = Me.ID
            .Execute
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this has really been so helpful i really appreciate

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try manually to run the SQL with some values.

You probably need to use either parameters or to concatenate the variables properly, for example using my function [CSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589800/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-whats-the-error/43591778#43591778).