# How to save from a form to a table?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I have a form `InventoryForm` and a table `StockRecords`. I'm trying to get the records in the form to save to the table `AfterUpdate`. Both my form and table have fields `EmployeeName`, `PartNo`, `Quantity`, `BinNo`, `Supplier`, `Shelf`, `Description`, `Price` & `TargetStockLevel`.

The form `AfterUpdate`'s VBA code (that I've seen working for others online but not for me) is:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO StockRecord (EmployeeName, PartNo, Quantity, BinNo, Supplier, Shelf, Discription, Price, TargetStockLevel) VALUES ('" & Me.SelectName & "', '" & Me.PartNo & "', '" & Me.Quantity & "', '" & Me.BinNo & "', '" & Me.Supplier & "','" & Me.Shelf & "', '" & Me.Discription & "', '" & Me.Price & "', '" & Me.TargetStockLevel & "' )"
End Sub
```

Edit :

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate() 
    'add data to table
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO StockRecord(EmployeeName, PartNo, Quantity, BinNo, Supplier, Shelf, Discription, Price, TargetStockLevel) " & _
    " VALUES ('" & Me.cboSelectName & "', '" & Me.cboPartNo & "','" & _
    Me.txtQuantity_Entered & "', '" & Me.txtBinNo & "', '" & Me.txtSupplier & "','" & Me.txtShelf & "', '" & Me.txtDiscription & "', '" & Me.txtPrice & "', '" & Me.txtTargetStockLevel & "' )"
End Sub
```

This new VBA code worked once but now won't (even when I made no changes). I get a message saying :

> *Compile Error : method or data member not found*.

All fields are text boxes, except two combo boxes (`SelectName` & `PartNo`). How to fix this?

Comment: I should also mention, the form is already updating another table (to which it is bound to) to change quantity levels. So i cant use                                                               DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord      
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

Comment: _Bind_ your form to the table. That's the magic of Access. And go get a tutorial: _Beginning with Microsoft Access_ or similar.

Comment: Am I able to bind it to two tables though ? My form is updating quantities of stock in one table called 'Inventory', but i'm trying to add the records of the form to another table 'StockRercord' so that i can see a transaction log of parts being used (by who and when).

Comment: There are many ways to maintain a log table. I would use VBA to update a recordset holding the logtable. With SQL - as you currently use - start by using the correct syntax - not all values are text. See my function [CSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589800/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-whats-the-error/43591778#43591778).

Comment: Is something in your code highlighted when you get the compile error?  If so, what?  Me.txtDiscription or something else?

Comment: Thank Gustav. HansUp, yes thats exactly what happened. I removed the 'cbo' and 'txt' before each field name in the code and it seems to have fixed it. It is working well for me now :)