# syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '2020-12-01'

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, syntax, syntax-error

I wrote this code. When I try to activate this sub I always get this problem "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '2020-12-01'". It's something wrong with Date (data in Polish means date).

Could u help me to fix this ?? I just want to take "Kolejka", "stadion", "Data" from form and add to my table Rozgrywki.
I also attached pictures of this error and picture of my form in access.

[Runtime error "3075"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD2Vw.png)
[Dialog being composed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGfxu.png)

```
 Public Sub Dodaj(Kolejka, stadion, Data, DA, DB, Optional wa = 0, Optional wb = 0)
    If [wa] = "" Then wa = 0
    If [wb] = "" Then wb = 0
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    dodaj_rozgrywka = "" & _
            "INSERT INTO Rozgrywki ( IDStadionu, Data, Idkolejki)" & _
            "SELECT " & stadion & " AS Wyr1, #" & Data & "# AS Wyr2;, " & Kolejka & " AS Wyr3;"
    DoCmd.RunSQL (dodaj_rozgrywka)
```

Comment: Remove the `;` after `Wyr2` and `Wyr3`.

Comment: I did this already and thats doesnt work.

Comment: I gues its something wrong with access. I dont may be should i change date format. May be u could code for the change of date format ??

Comment: Can your format the date to get: `#01/12/2020#`. That is based on examples [found here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762#__toc358028377). I'll also add the ms-access tag, might attract more users.

Comment: Yea its actually my first code ? :) I am earning vba and sql also its my first time in this portal :)

Comment: i will try to find something about this

Answer (score 0):

Format your date value to a string expression:

```vb
"SELECT " & stadion & " AS Wyr1, #" & Format(Data, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AS Wyr2;, " & Kolejka & " AS Wyr3;"
```

Or use my [CSql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43591778/3527297) function. Even better, learn yourself to use queries with *parameters*.

Comment: Then are inserting data that don't match your table. Print out the SQL and run it manually to debug.