# TransferSpreadsheet export leading apostrophe

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-excel

I use some vba to export the results of a select query. The selected data needs to be exported 1 on 1 to Excel. This morning I faced the following error:

```
3274 on DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, External table is not in the expected format
```

Inspecting the source data, I've found a row containing a leading Apostrophe. Removing this row from the source, solved the error. However, I need this row to be exported as well. Is there any setting to solve this problem?

This is the VBA:

```
lSQL = ""
lSQL = lSQL & "select a.* from table As e "
Set lQD = lDB.CreateQueryDef("Test", lSQL)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet A_EXPORT, 10, "Test", FileName, True
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `table` (or `lSQL`) with a simple *select query*.

In this query, sanitize the field contents using my [CSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589800/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-whats-the-error/43591778#43591778) function or similar. It will *double* single-quotes which, I believe, should be the cure.