# Please assist with adding the value of Text34 from the user into thisParcel expression on MS ACCESS. I get a 3075 run time error when I run the code

Tags: ms-access

Please assist with adding the value of Text34 from the user into thisParcel expression on MS ACCESS. I get a 3075 run time error when I run the code. I have rechecked my indentation, missing operators, but I cannot find the problem.

Private Sub Command10_Click()

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)

i = Val(Text2.Value)
w = Val(Text34.Value)

    If Text8 = "" Or IsNull(Text8) Then
        TrueOrFalse = 0
    Else
        TrueOrFalse = -1
    End If
    
    If IsNull(Len(List0.Value)) Then
        MsgBox "Choose allotment area"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    thisParcel = List0.Value & Left("00000000", 8 - Len(Trim(Str(i)))) & Trim(Str(i)) + 
                 Left("00000", 5 - Len(Trim(Str(w)))) & Trim(Str(w))
    
           
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Schedule ( DiagramNo, OnGP, GPNo, ParcelCode, DiagramDeedNo ) VALUES ( '" & Text6.Value & "', " & TrueOrFalse & " , '" & Text8.Value & "' , '" & thisParcel & " , '" & Text22 & "');"
```

Comment: It would help a lot with some sample values and expected results.

Comment: Try a `Debug.Print` to see the value of `thisParcel`. Also it can help to build the SQL statement into a string (`strSQL="INSERT INTO Schedule......`) so that you can `Debug.Print` that as well.

Comment: Hi Gustav, the result must look like this x06700240000000100000. The First 8 digits are from List0, the next 8 are from textbox2, and the last 5 are from textbox34.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos, miss a line continuation, and the code can be reduced a little:

```vb
If IsNull(List0.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Choose allotment area"
    Exit Sub
End If
    
TrueOrFalse = (Nz(Me!Text8.Value, "") <> "")
    
thisParcel = List0.Value & _
    Left("00000000", 8 - Len(CStr(i))) & CStr(i) & _
    Left("00000", 5 - Len(CStr(w))) & CStr(w)
               
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Schedule ( DiagramNo, OnGP, GPNo, ParcelCode, DiagramDeedNo ) VALUES ( '" & Text6.Value & "', " & TrueOrFalse & ", '" & Text8.Value & "', '" & thisParcel & "', '" & Text22 & "');"
```

Also, consider my function [CSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589800/syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-whats-the-error/43591778#43591778).

Comment: Hi Gustav, Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: "did not work" doesn't tell anything. So, double-check your values.